# Nested modules/components in Angular 2/4

Tags: angular

I have this structure:

```
App/dashboard/dashboard.module.ts
App/dashboard/dashboard.component.ts
App/dashboard/dashboard.component.html
App/dashboard/routes.ts
App/app.module.ts
App/app.component.ts
App/app.component.html
```

Inside the app/dashboard folder there is another sub component. On the dashboard.component.html are the

With this approach, how to import a service that I can use on the sub components of dashboard? If I use [providers] on app.module.ts can it be accessed on the rest of the modules/components? And, if I want a new component at the same level of app.module.ts, can I use the router-outlet of the dashboard.component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nested is achieved with [router](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html)

You have `routes.ts` in this module you create new path, add component and add children:

```
    const crisisCenterRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'index',
    component: BaseComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'main',
        component: ChildComponent,
        children: [
          {
            path: ':id',
            component: ChildChildComponent
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

In BaseComponent template.html add  `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`:

```
<div>..html..  <router-outlet></router-outlet>  </div>
```

by parity of reasoning in `ChildComponent` in template add `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`

you nested success

Comment: is it allowed to have a module and other components inside a module?

Answer (score 0):

service only add to module once, and you can use everywhere.

reference this article!

> https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/ngmodule-faq.html#!#q-module-provider-visibility

*And, if I want a new component at the same level of app.module.ts, can use the router-outlet of the dashboard.component?*

you can use the route, but it's strange in your structure...

Comment: Thanks my friend. Please take a look of this: https://github.com/creativetimofficial/light-bootstrap-dashboard-angular/tree/master/app here is the template that I use. The author use this structure.

Comment: @AliBriceño This structure should be fine, you can use it
but this author doesn't have that like you say